# EF6 how to check if database model is newer than app model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I create an application where many clients use one database. When I create a migration, I have to update the applications to the latest version on all computers. Sometimes it is impossible at one moment. Clients then turn on my application and the application throws an error because it sees that the database is from a newer migration. How to check if the database is from a newer migration in EF6 to handle such an exception and display the appropriate message to the user? It is best to do it in Program.cs at the very beginning of the application start.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have a code that guards the entry point of the application. Inside this code, consult an extra table in your database. In the table, store the database version as a string, in whatever format you want. The application also has a string - the expected version of the database. The two either match (the database is migrated to the latest version) or the database version is higher (the app hasn't been updated). This second case just stops your application. The last possible case (the database version is lower) means that the migration possibly failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the actual version of a database in the migration history table `__MigrationHistory` containing a `MigrationId` column which should give you what you want. Here's an article showing how to work with it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a web app but if you must go the desktop or mobile native route then you can safeguard your application by forcing users to update.

You can create a table in your database as follows:

```
Application | CurrentVersion| MinVersion
```

1. If `Client.Version < Server.CurrentVersion` then provide the user with optional upgrade notification
2. If `Client.Version < Server.MinVersion` then force the user to upgrade